# Why does the pointer get printed twice in C?

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, c-strings

If I compile the following code and run it with `gcc source.c && ./a.out`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "My string";
    char m = string[0];
    printf("%s\n", &m);
}
```

I get `MMy string` as the output, but if I do

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "My string";
    char m = string[0];
    printf("%s\n", &string[0]);
}
```

I get just `My string` as expected. What is going on here? I noticed that if I define the pointer as a variable, e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "My string";
    char *m = &string[0];
    printf("%s\n", m);
}
```

Then again I get `My string` as expected.
Why does the value of the pointer get printed twice in the first example?

Comment: The first example is UB because you print something no being a C type string using `%s`. Your misunderstanding seems to be that you expect that `&m` is the same as `&string[0]`. But it's no. `m` and `string[0]` belongs to two different objects.

Comment: Yep, that was exactly it! Thanks for your comment

Comment: You should activate warnings when compiling and read them.

Comment: @klutt Interestingly, even if I compile with `gcc -Wall source.c && ./a.out`, there are no warnings for the culprit program. Or did you mean something else when you said activate warnings?

Comment: @ChristofferCorfieldAakre Yes, I realized that now.

Comment: It's still good advise and it was also the first "negligence" on your side that struck me.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I was actually already compiling with warnings but I decided to turn them off for this post to create a "minimal working example", but in hindsight I guess that doesn't really make any sense. Thanks anyway for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first program has undefined behavior.

The expression &m does not point to a character of a string. It points to a single object of the type char

```
char string[] = "My string";
char m = string[0];
```

After the object m there can be anything in the memory. It just occurred such a way that after the object m there is the array string without any gap.

But the conversion specifier %s expects a pointer to a string that is to a sequence of characters that is terminated by the zero character '\0'.

In the second program the pointer m points to the first character of the string stored in the array string.

```
char string[] = "My string";
char *m = &string[0];
```

So the second program is correct.